# How do I get notified of automatic "apt-get update" errors?

Tags: apt, debian-stretch

On a Debian Stretch server, APT ist configured via `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` to automatically update itself every day.
Hadn't I run "apt-get update" manually by chance, I wouldn't have noticed this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/stretch/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B188E2B695BD4743
```

I downloaded the updated GPG key to fix the problem, but I need a way to be informed by APT when things go wrong. The server was missing two PHP updates because of this.

https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades mentions "APT::Periodic::Verbose", but this doesn't allow to only be notified about errors (and I really don't need a mail from all 50 servers every day...)

edit 2019-05-13: The package unattended-upgrades is not installed, and I don't want to use it. APT should only update itself, not upgrade.

Comment: Wasn't there some switch like `MailOnlyOnError` for UA? Can't check it locally atm

Comment: afaics, this only applies to "Unattended-Upgrade" which I don't want to use. Only automatic update of the packages-list, no upgrade.

Comment: Hm. Why do you use unattended upgrades then, and not something like cron-apt?

Comment: Again, I'm not using unattended upgrades. Only updates.

Comment: ...yes, obviously using the package "unattended upgrades", which you yourself linked in your question. _As of Debian 9 (Stretch) both the unattended-upgrades and apt-listchanges packages are installed by default_

Comment: Linking to an URL doesn't imply that I have installed the package for unattended upgrades. For clarity: It is not installed, and I don't want to use it.